# Why output is duplicated?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, foreach

Fetching data from firebase database and my output to simulator is duplicated. I know why data is pushed 2 times to 'items'. How can i solve this issue and push items from every child to 'addData' only once?

My code:

```
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            arrData:[]
        };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
      var self = this;
       var items = [];
       database.ref("eventAttenders/2188058178082419").orderByKey().once("value")
         .then(function(snapshot) {
           snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
             var key = childSnapshot.key;
             const key = childSnapshot.key;
             database.ref(`users/${key}`).once("value")
               .then(function(snapshot) {
                 snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
                   var data = snapshot.val();
                   items.push({
                     name: data.name,
                     phone: data.phone,
                   });
               });

             });

         });

       });
       self.setState({arrData: items})
 }
```

Database screenshot:

[image]

Simulator screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are adding the push method in `snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {` this not required, try removing it.

```
componentDidMount = () => {
      var self = this;
       var items = [];
       database.ref("eventAttenders/2188058178082419").orderByKey().once("value")
         .then(function(snapshot) {
           snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
             var key = childSnapshot.key;
             const key = childSnapshot.key;
             database.ref(`users/${key}`).once("value")
               .then(function(snapshot) {
                   var data = snapshot.val();
                   items.push({
                     name: data.name,
                     phone: data.phone,
                   });
             });

         });

       });
       self.setState({arrData: items})
 }
```

Comment: But how can i get data to arrData then? Sorry, i'm beginner. Only one month practice.

Comment: Okey. I figured it out finally.